# OpenCV C++ Homograpy RANSAC

Tags: c++, opencv, homography, ransac

When using `findHomography` as used the [OpenCV Features2D + Homography Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html), it calls on `CV_RANSAC` as its third parameter:

```
Mat H = findHomography(obj, scene, CV_RANSAC);
```

But in some examples I've seen, you can add in a number after, like this:

```
Mat H = findHomography(obj, scene, CV_RANSAC, 5);
```

What does this do?

And is there a way of altering `CV_RANSAC` to perform better, or is it just called like this to do its job as best it can?

Comment: You may want to look to the documentation: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findhomography

Answer (score 1):

At the top of the page that you posted is the link to the [API documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=findhomography#findhomography) of that function.

The fourth parameter is the allowed reprojection error in pixels, so that the reprojection still counts as a match.

Comment: What does _the allowed reprojection error in pixels_ mean though?

Comment: when you apply the homography to a keypoint (from your matching), how much distance (in pixel) may the corresponding keypoint from your matching have to be counted as an inlier.

Comment: So a radius of failure? Whats a good amount to set this at? I know it says 1 to 10 but why is 10 the suggested max?

Comment: Depends fully on your goal and requirements. It might be OK to set a really high threshold if you intend to refine the result using some other method later. If the result is your final result, and you need high accuracy, then you might need to set the threshold really low (<1.0).

Comment: Drpends on your image resolution and how much your scene conflicts with homography assumptions (e.g. that the scene is planar or the camera doesnt move)